# Calculating future average

Tags: average

I have an average of `3,5` over 16 data points. If I wish to increase this average to, say, `6`, how many future data points must be of a certain value? Assume all future data points are of the same value.

If the current average of 16 data points is `3,5`, then four new data points each of value `7` would result in a new average of `4,2`.

I know how to calculate this by hand. What I'm looking for is some formula that I can plug in to my spreadsheet.

Would it be possible to calculate how many data points are needed to reach an average of `6`, given each new data point has a value of `7`? Also, would it be possible to reverse the unknown(say I know there will be 20 more data points. What does each value have to be to reach a new average of `6`)?

Is there a term for this type of formula/problem? I tried searching for a solution but I'm not quite sure what I'm supposed to search for.

Comment: The total of your $16$ points is $3.5\times 16$.  If you wish to add $N$ new points, each with value $v$, then the new average will be $\frac {3.5\times 16+v\times N}{16+N}$.  You can set this to whatever you like.  Of course, to get numerical values, you'll ned to specify either $v$ or $N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of thinking about this is to consider the current total sum in any situation. In the beginning, you have $16$ data points and their total sum is $3.5 \cdot 16 = 56$. Now, you wish to add some terms, let's say $n$ terms (a known number), of value $x$ so that the new average is $\mu_{new}$. This just means that the new total sum is
$$
56 + nx = (16+n)\mu_{new}
$$
from which you can solve for $x$:
$$
x = \frac{(16+n)\mu_{new} - 56}{n}
$$
If instead you know $x$, you can solve for $n$:
$$
n = \frac{ 16\mu_{new}-56 }{x -\mu_{new}}
$$

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! That makes so much sense and worked out perfectly in my spreadsheet :)

Comment: Would you be able to explain to me how you go about to solve for `n`? I don't understand how you got rid of the parenthesis and how `µnew` ended up negative, nor how it ended up next to `x`(sorry, I don't know what the part above or below the line, or what the line is called in English).

Comment: Starting with
$$
56+nx = (16+n)\mu_{new}
$$
Opening the parentheses results in
$$
56+nx = 16\mu_{new} + n \mu_{new}
$$
Then move the terms with $n$ to the left and other terms to the right:
$$
nx - n \mu_{new} = 16\mu_{new} - 56
$$
Can you finish from here?